# Need help for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def a(inp):
    i = 0
    x = 0

    for i in range(len(inp)):
        b(x)
        print(x)

def b(x1):
    x1 = x1 + 1

def c ():
    a1 = a("...")

c()
```

This code gives the output:

```
0
0
0
```

I don't understand why `x` value doesn't change?

Comment: You are printing x (x=0) three times. Function b(x1) does not return anything. The call to function b(x) is not assigned to a variable...

Comment: Why should ``x`` change? The code does not attempt to change it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a concept of mutable and non mutable things. Mutable things include things like list, dict etc. But an integer is non-mutable, so when you change it you have to reassign it back.

for e.g.

```
def b(l):
    l += [1]


a= [1,2,3]
b(a)
print(a)

def c(l):
    l += 1


a= 1
c(a)
print(a)
```

This code with output

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
1
```

Since int is non mutable and list is mutable. For more you can check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutable-vs-immutable-objects-in-python/.

Comment: It should be noted though that immutability vs mutability *isn't* really the main issue here. If you simply replaced the int they're passing with a list, you'd get the same behavior as they originally had. The key is that for lists, `+=` isn't actually reassignment, it's a mutation of the list in place. So the real point isn't immutability vs mutability, it's assigning vs mutation.

Comment: @Carcigenicate very well said.

Answer (score 0):

`x1 = x1 + 1` can't change `x`. `x` is passed as a value* to `b`. Reassigning `x1` will only change what value `x1` is looking at. Returning the value from the function and reassigning it at the call site would be the simplest way to achieve what you want:

```
 . . .
    for i in range (len(inp)):
        x = b(x)
        print(x)

def b(x1):
   return x1 + 1
```

---

`*` It's a little more complicated than that, but that's the simplest way to think about it for now while dealing with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`x1 = x1 + 1` in your function `b(x1)` doesn't change the value of the variable passed into `b()`. So outside the function, x remains unchanged at 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's just changing the `x1` variable in that function's scope. To assign it to `x`, return the new value:

```py
def b(x1):
    return x1 = x1 + 1
```

Then set the return value to `x`:

```py
for i in range (len(inp)):
    x = b(x)
    print(x)
```

It is also recommended to do get the value of `i`, as it is the position.